# ServiceNow integration with .NET

Tags: c#, soap, servicenow

I have been trying to get an insertResponse from the ServiceNow web-service.
I know that the **elementFormDefault** property under Webservices need to be set to *False*.

Since I do not have an admin login, I cannot do so.
Is there an alternate?
I need a response from the web-service, be it a Boolean that a new record is created.
Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You're in luck! You can specify a URL parameter in your WSDL URL to drive `elementFormDefault`.

Add this to your WSDL URL:

> `elementFormDefault=qualified`

...here's what a full URL would look like:

```
https://<instance name>.service-now.com/<table name>.do?WSDL&elementFormDefault=qualified
```

You can validate this by simply loading up the WSDL in your browser and looking for this XML snippet at the top:

> `<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"`

Comment: that was really helpful. but I am still getting the response as null in my .NET code.

CorrectReference.insert insert = new ServiceNowTicketing.CorrectReference.insert();
            CorrectReference.insertResponse response = new ServiceNowTicketing.CorrectReference.insertResponse();

response = soapClient.insert(insert);
:( :(

Comment: The override on the URL was a stroke of brilliance.  It fixed my issue without changing the ServiceNow defaults.   Thanks